# Running Python scripts on Apache Server: 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, python, ubuntu-14.04, http-status-code-403

I need to run a few python scripts on a subdomain of my website set up using Apache on an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu. I tried following some of the steps mentioned in this [post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-apache-mysql-and-python-lamp-server-without-frameworks-on-ubuntu-14-04). I get a 403 error ("Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /index.py on this server.") while trying to access the subdomain.

I have a *755(-rwxr-xr-x)* permission on the *index.py* file.

The *subdomain.website.com.conf* file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@website.com
    ServerName subdomain.website.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain.website.com/public_html
    Options +ExecCGI
    DirectoryIndex index.py
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad!

The directives *Options* and *DirectoryIndex* needed to be inside *Directory* tags.

The correct *subdomain.website.com.conf* file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@website.com
        ServerName subdomain.website.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain.website.com/public_html
        <Directory /var/www/html/subdomain.website.com/public_html>
                Options +ExecCGI
                DirectoryIndex index.py
        </Directory>
        AddHandler cgi-script .py
</VirtualHost>
```